# Android not writing files in sd card

Tags: applications, storage

I am not getting why inspite of having a 16 GB SD card in my android the apps from play store are not getting directly stored in SD card by default. Due to this its becoming hard for me to use the device as every time I have to flush lots of data from the device memory to install some new app.

Comment: @SLY A link-only comment or an answer becomes unhelpful when the link becomes obsolete. Please always provide a brief context in the comment whenever you suggest an off-site link in it.

Comment: Can't you install a better system on your device like CyanogenMod or Debian?

Answer (score 0):

Some ROMS have an option Default Write Disk (or something similar) under Storage settings, change that to External memory.